# How to set cookie using JavaScript after fetching API request in GCM Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, django, cookies, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I have successfully implemented GCM and ServiceWorkers to receive push-notification.

**My problem**

Whenever there is a SOS update, I am sending a HTTP request to [gcm-http](https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send) which then shows up a normal notification on Google Chrome but without any payload or data.

According to [Google Developers Doc](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web), chrome cannot receive payload/data, so one have to manually fetch the notification from the backend when *push event* is triggered.

So to fetch the data I am requesting an url on my backend (in django) to send me the notification data. But **problem lies here** how will I know which notification's data I have to send from my database/model?

Note:- I am not maintaining a different `database table/model` to determine notifications read by the client, since its an **SOS** update and read/unread is not required.

**Workaround which is not working:-**

I can set a cookie on client's browser and on backend can get next notification (below is the code)

```
class GetSOSNotification(View):
    notif_id = 0

    def get(self, request):
        if 'last_notif_id' in request.COOKIES:
            notif_id = request.COOKIES.get('last_notif_id') + 1
            sos = SOSUpdate.objects.get(id=notif_id)
        else:
            sos = SOSUpdate.objects.order_by('-timestamp').filter()[0]
            notif_id = sos.id

        data = dict()
        data['notification'] = dict()
        if sos.get_condition_display() and sos.get_subject_display():
            data['notification']['title'] = sos.polling_station.name + " " + sos.get_subject_display() + " " + sos.get_condition_display()
        elif sos.get_condition_display():
            data['notification']['title'] = sos.polling_station.name + " " + sos.get_condition_display()
        elif sos.get_subject_display():
            data['notification']['title'] = sos.polling_station.name + " " + sos.get_subject_display()
        else:
            data['notification']['title'] = sos.polling_station.name + " SOS Alert!"

        if sos.message:
            data['notification']['message'] = sos.message
        else:
            data['notification']['message'] = "Please click here to check the details."

        data['notification']['notif_id'] = notif_id

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

but, I **have** to return JSON response, and therefoe I can't set cookie from server-side, therefore I planned to use `data['notification']['notif_id']` on client-side (i.e., Javascript) to set cookie.

My **SW.js**'s snippet looks like :

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    fetch("//localhost/get_sos_notification/").then(function(response){
        if(response.status!=200){
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
            throw new Error();
        }
        return response.json().then(function(data){
            if(data.error || !data.notification){
                console.error('The API returned an error.', data.error);
                throw new Error();
            }
            var title = data.notification.title;
            var message = data.notification.message;
            var icon = '//localhost/static/main/images/push-notification.png';
            var notificationTag = data.notification.tag;
            return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
              body: message,
              icon: icon,
              tag: notificationTag
            });
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
       console.log('Unable to retrieve data', err);
       var title = 'SOS - Update';
       var message = 'We were unable to get the information, please click here to know the real message.';
       var icon = '//localhost/static/main/images/push-notification.png';
       var notificationTag = 'notification-error';
       return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
           body: message,
           icon: icon,
           tag: notificationTag
       });
    })
  );
});
```

But I am not able to do `document.cookie = last_notif_id=data.notification.notif_id` at the place where I am handling received notification data (if successfully received), because the JS script is giving error `Unable to retrieve data ReferenceError: document is not defined at http://localhost/static/main/js/sw.js`

**Additional information:** `//localhost/get_sos_notification/` is a GET request, returns JSON, and is mapped to `class GetSOSNotification(View)`

I have googled and searched SO a lot, but haven't got any solution.

Thanks in advance.